# Android: Google Fit not finding data sources for DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE

Tags: android, google-fit

I have some code that has worked for months in production which suddenly has stopped working yesterday in all my apps.
I use Google Fit to retrieve locations via the Fitness.SensorClient API.
Locations permissions are requested correctly to the user at installation time (both the generic Android FINE_LOCATION permission and the permission to read and store locations into Google Fit).
I create the Fitness Option in this way:

```
setFitnessOptions(
            FitnessOptions.builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE));
```

I then look for the DataSources in this way:

```
GoogleSignInAccount lastSignedAccount = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, getFitnessOptions());
    if (lastSignedAccount != null) {
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(context, lastSignedAccount)
                .findDataSources(
                        new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
                                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                                .build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
                                for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());
```

...

The value of the parameter dataSources in OnSuccessListener is an empty list. If I try other data types .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA),  dataSources is not an empty list. However neither DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE nor DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK return any data source.

I have checked the release notes of google services and nothing relevant seems to have changed. 
The code above seems to be equivalent to all the examples provided by Google, e.g. [this one](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors)

Does anyone have an idea of why suddenly that code has stopped working? Thanks

UPDATE: I have verified that it does not work with Android 6, 7, 8, or 9.

Comment: I have also an issue which just came up a few days ago : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855759/android-google-fit-data-upload-error-5002-datatypes-name-does-not-match-p Seems like Google changed something wo announcing anything...

Comment: Just noticed replacing DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE with DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK resolves the issue for me.

Comment: thanks for your answers. Using DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK does not solve the issue for me. If I use STEPS_DELTA it works - but that is a completely different type

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. In another part of my code I was subscribing using GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount. Apparently this may cause a mismatch and the locations are not returned. Changing the subscription to GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension solved the issue