# Android + Google Fit Data Upload : error 5002 - DataType's name does not match package name

Tags: android, google-fit

In an app we upload user activity data to Google Fit like this :

```
   Fitness.getSessionsClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context))
                            .insertSession(((SessionInsertRequest) object))
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    // At this point, the session has been inserted and can be read.
                                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Session insert was successful!");
                                    }
                                     //more success handling
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem inserting the session: " + e.toString()+ "\n"+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                    }
                                    //more error handling
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

This was working fine until approx sep 4 2019.

Then Google seemed to have changed something resulting in the following warning when creating the SessionInsertRequest

> App com.foo.bar does not have access to data types in request

and in onFailureListener(...) we get the following message:

> There was a problem inserting the session: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5002: DataType's name does not match package name.

DataTypes were not changed. They are requested when the user is asked to give permission to upload :

```
   private FitnessOptions getFitnessSignInOptions(OAuthType type) {

    switch (type) {

        case Activity:
            return FitnessOptions.builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                    .build();
    }
}
```

and created in a DataSource like :

```
 DataSource  locationDataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(packageName)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
            .setName(uniqueIdentifier + "-locations")
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();
```

similar as the [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistorySessions/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistorysessions/MainActivity.java#L271) shows.

It does not matter if we omit setting the name of the dataSource or using  setName(packageName). Also using setStreamName(packageName) instead does not resolve the issue.
Anybody else having this or a similar issue ?

Thank you

Robert

Comment: Just noticed replacing DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE with DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK resolves the error. However, I'm not sure if I can just change the data type, or what is the actual difference between them...

Comment: TRACK is different from SAMPLE as the timestamp is not precise

Comment: Yes, looks like something regarding TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE changed. I'm uploading location related data, so for me the difference regarding the timestamps is not very important, however data with TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK does not appear in the user's activity stream.

Comment: I solved your issue by upgrading all the libraries to the latest version, regenerating google-services.json, etc. I also updated Android Studio and the gradle plugin. I do not know what did the trick, as I followed a long process. I did it while I was trying to address a related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833033/android-google-fit-not-finding-data-sources-for-datatype-type-location-sample?noredirect=1#comment102154775_57833033

Comment: Could you specify what upgrades you did ? I tried yesterday using com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:18.0.0 and AndroidX but it made no difference to me...

Comment: I updated Android studio to the latest version, including all its plugins. I then updated all the libraries to the latest version using Android studio's editor's suggestions in the Gradle file. Fitness is  on v18.0.0. I was already on Android X. Then I went to the firebase console and downloaded the google-service.json file again after porting Crashlytics to Firebase, as it was still on Fabric.

Comment: I did all that besides the json file as I'm not using Firebase. Does not resolve for me :-/ And I actually don't want to add it only for resolving an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the issue is related to the use of GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount. Apparently in the new version of the library this is not liked.  Using GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension should do the trick. It worked for my issue [with locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833033/android-google-fit-not-finding-data-sources-for-datatype-type-location-sample)

Comment: Surprisingly recently every works for me using TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK. User sees map and distance of uploaded activity. I did not change anything. I'm still watching this, being unsure what is stable and what not :-/

Comment: TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK works only for certain (not too fast) bike rides. A road bike ride won't appear in Google Fit. No idea why. I applied your solution and using TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE is working again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may have provided an invalid google-services.json file or at least one that is not compatible with the one used when you acquired permission from the user to use Google Fit. 
I had the same issue: when I uploaded the new version of my app on top of the one downloaded from Google Play, it gave this error. It did not happen if instead I installed the new version of the app from scratch. 
Regenerating the google-services.json file on Firebase and giving it to the new version of the app solved the issue. Now I can upload the app on top of the existing one and I do not get this error any more.
Note however that before I did not have Firebase enabled so it is possible that Google does not allow any more using google-services.json that is not generated via Firebase

Comment: As mentioned before, I'm not using Firebase and google-services.json. Never needed it. I'm just using play-services-fitness module and TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE datatype stopped working. While TYPE_LOCATION_TRACK is working, which is completely senseless, though it does not create a map/locations in the users activity feed.

Comment: However I just double checked and created a Firebase project, download the json and integrated it. Still the same error occurs.